# How to make CSS animation to run each time the subsequent class is added to the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a CSS animation class setup so I can animate a

element.

When the input button is clicked, the class is added to the

and I am expecting that every time I click the input button in the example, the

will fly onto the screen.

However, it only works the first time and any subsequent clicks of the input do not make the element animate.  What am I missing here?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

jQuery('#cloc').click(function () {

jQuery('p').removeClass('anim').promise().done(function() {

jQuery('p').addClass('anim');

});



});


});
```

```css
input {
margin-bottom:20px;
margin-top:50px;
}

p {
  opacity:1;
}

.anim {
  animation-duration: 200ms;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
  transform:translateX(-200px);
   opacity:0;
  }



  to {
    transform:translateX(0px);
    opacity:1;
    
  }
}

p {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
opacity:0;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-iteration-count: 1;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative">
<p>
HERE IS A TESTER FOR YOU.
</p>
</div>
<input type="button" id="cloc" value="test">
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen with the text when the animation stops, to stay on the screen? If so your animation should start with removing the text first.

Comment: You could trigger 2 classes, one to play the animation and the second to remove the text setting it to the initial position.

Comment: @Azu I'll remove it eventually either by removing the class or adding another class that animates it off screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add new event listener to the **animationend** event for reset the property 
 **animation-name** to **none**

Like this below code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

      $('#cloc').click(function () {

        $('p').removeClass('anim').promise().done(function() {

          $('p').addClass('anim');

          setTimeout(function() {
              $('p').removeClass('anim');
          },1000);
    

        });

      });

    });
```

with use **toggleClass**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $para = $('p');

  $('#cloc').click(function() {

    $para.toggleClass('anim');

  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, but that doesn't seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/xstatic/opdzcvnr/18/

Comment: Also if I remove the animation name, what happens when I add the class again?

Comment: If you remove the animation-name property, the animation will not run even if you add the class again

Comment: I just updated the previous solution, you can go through again with my code, Then let me know

Comment: That seems to work, but isn't really what I am looking for.  I don't want a timeout to reset it, I want a subsequent button click to reset it.  The timeout is resetting it at a time I don't want it reset.  The order should be:

1.  Click the button.
2.  Element goes to opacity 0 and offscreen and transitions to opacity 1 and on screen and stays on screen until the button is clicked again.
3.  If I click the button again, it resets and happens again.

Comment: so for this you can use toggleClass. I just updated the code, go through again toggleClass  which I have mentioned

Comment: yeah toggleclass seems to work great.  thank you!